# How to compress huge java-script framework into few files (including sub directory's)

Tags: javascript

I have a huge javascript framework with sub directories that contains a lot of JavaScript includes to other JavaScript files, how can I take these JavaScript files and compress them to  a single or very few compressed JavaScript
files?

Comment: This is a pretty horrendous question.  Odd seeing that you have 6k reputation.

Comment: There are many compilers can do this for you, free and open source. On linux you can try this https://github.com/dfsq/compressJS.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with "jsmin" or "closure-compiler".

- http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html
- https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/

Answer (score 2):

You will want to do this through some sort of `build` process. JavaScript has tools for this like [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/). Using these tools you will write a build script that uses something like [uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) to do the actual minification.